# WPF Binding in TextBlock.Text to Validation.Errors not working

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, data-binding

I have an ItemsControl which is validated by an object on the DataContext that implements INotifyDataErrorInfo. The intended effect is for the validation error to show below the control in a TextBlock, rather than the conventional red border and tooltip style.

Upon validation, my TextBlock appears, but it's Text is empty - there's something wrong with my binding to the validation error, but I can't figure out what.

Also, the TextBlock overlaps the control below the ItemsControl it rather than making extra space for itself. How can I solve these issues?

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem as your first issue a few days ago. When I examine the control inside the `ErrorTemplate` by using Snoop, I found out that the DataContext inside the ErrorTemplate is already of type `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ValidationError>`. So you can just use `<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />`, no need for casting and setting the `RelativeResource`.

Comment: +1 I've not known about this, maybe I found my own solution which is a bit hacky and satisfied with it.

Comment: Yup - that works exactly as expected, thanks! now if I could just get the template to make space for itself. it seems to be positioned absolutely rather than as part of the document flow, which makes sense if you want to just draw a red border, but is weirdly restrictive if you want to do anything else.

Comment: Have you tried using `DockPanel` instead? I use it to show a warning icon to the right of the placeholder, i.e. Dock.Right on the icon.